# É possível gerar script de uma tabela, a partir de um comando SQL?

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server, script, tabela-html

Gostaria de gerar script de criação de uma tabela, a partir de um comando SQL assim eu poderia construir um programa que fosse capaz de clonar tabelas.

Estou utilizando SQL Server 2008 R2 e preciso implementar uma rotina de clonagem de tabelas, dentro de uma aplicação escrita em VB.NET.

Dessa forma, eu escolheria o banco e as tabelas deste banco que seriam clonadas e então eu as jogaria em uma outra base de dados que receberia este espelhamento.

Comment: Pode explicar melhor o que pretende e dar um exmplo para perceber-mos melhor?

Comment: Amigo, como o @Sergio disse, detalhe mais seu problema. Sim é completamente possível, tudo depende do que você está utilizando. MySql? SQL_Server? Oracle? Aí poderemos te ajudar melhor.

Comment: como o @FernandoA.W disse é possivel mas depende de cada banco exemplo o SQLite seria assim `PRAGMA table_info(nome_tabela);` acredido que para os outros seja semelhante também, basta dar uma lida na documentação do banco que utiliza.

Comment: Precisa ser através de um comando SQL? E que base você está usando? Se for MySQL, o programa `mysqldump` (que vem com o MySQL) permite exportar a estrutura de uma tabela ou da base toda.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Existem inúmeras formas de fazer, algumas mais dentro do padrão, outras nem tanto, algumas mais simples, algumas mais específicas mas acho que é isto que está querendo:

```
CREATE TABLE tabela_nova AS
   (SELECT * FROM tabela_existente);
```

Não sei se funciona em todos os banco de dados (testado no PostgreSQL), mas você não especificou nenhum. Note que só copia a tabela, nada que possa estar relacionada a ela.

Se quiser só copiar a estrutura sem copiar os dados basta colocar uma condição que certamente seja falsa:

```
CREATE TABLE tabela_nova AS
   (SELECT * FROM tabela_existente WHERE 1=2);
```

Para o **SQL Server** pode ser:

```
SELECT * INTO tabela_nova From tabela_existente WHERE 1=2;
```

Como o código acima parece não funcionar no MySQL, talvez isto funcione apenas nele:

```
CREATE TABLE tabela_nova LIKE tabela_existente;
```

Em SQLite é para funcionar do jeito padrão mas pode ter alguns efeitos colaterais como perda de tipos. Existe uma outra forma. Você pode pegar como a tabela original foi criada facilmente no próprio SQLite. Ele armazena o comando SQL que foi usado para criar a original. Dali você pode adaptar para criar sua nova tabela. Os dados ficam gravados na tabela `sqlite_master`:

```
SELECT sql FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name='mytable';
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura.](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Select/CreateTable.sql)

Comment: Tentei aqui no MySQL  não esta a bumbar. Seria bom indicares onde fizeste @bigown.

Comment: Não fiz e eu disse que não sei em quais bancos vai funcionar, mas isto é bem básico de SQL. Como o MySQL não segue muito o padrão, imaginava que nele não funcionaria mesmo.

Comment: Uma dúvida (debaixo dessa ainda). Desse jeito até os relacionamentos e tudo associado é "copiado"?

Comment: Não, isto copia só a tabela mesmo, não copia mais nada, índices, nada.

Comment: Obrigado @bigown.

Comment: Os índices vão sim, @Cold: "Use LIKE to create an empty table based on the definition of another table, including any column attributes and indexes defined in the original table" (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html).

Comment: @bfavaretto estava lendo agora que o método do MySQL vai mesmo mas o original que eu usei não vai.

Comment: @bigown funcionou no sqlserver cara, valeu! :D